# How can I set the color of the border area around the page/post on my Wordpress Site

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the colors on a my WordPress site. I've made progress with the body of the posts/pages (as seen in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109494)). However, I haven't been able to extend it to the border of the post/page body.

My experimental site can be found [here](http://www.underwaterfootball.com/wpdev/)

See the circled areas in the following screen shot:
[image: example screen shot]

I've managed to change the body color by setting the background color for .grid and .page.
However the border around the text still eludes me.

Here's what I think are the relevant elements.

```
<body class="home blog custom-background">
    <div id="container" class="hfeed">
        <div id="header">         
            <div id="logo">
                <!-- stuff -->
            </div><!-- end of #logo -->
            <!-- stuff -->
        </div><!-- end of #header -->

    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
            <div id="content-blog" class="grid col-940">
                <div id="post-8" class="post-8 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
       <!-- more stuff -->
```

Doing the same trick .clearfix doesn't work for me. So I'm missing something fundamental here. What have I missed? How do I reverse engineer the CSS to figure out what class to alter?

Comment: This sort of thing is trivial to figure out if you use inspection tools. Popular choices include Chrome/Safari's built in Developer Tools, and Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot. I already got as far as I did with Chrome's Inspect Element, and then hit a road block. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That white space is not `border`, it's just the `background-color` of `#wrapper` element:

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: #991A1A; /* <-- Change this */
}
```

> How do I reverse engineer the CSS to figure out what class to alter?

Simply use *Developer tools* on Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome. you can press right-click on every element on the page, select `Inspect element` and check the *Metrics*, *Styles*, *Computed Styles* and much more on the opened panel.

Comment: awsome... the #wrapper (especially the #) was the piece I was missing